# What should be done with the [setup] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was recently browsing the tags and I noticed something weird. The [setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setup) tag. Currently we can split up the tag into two separate categories.

1. Questions about configuring operating systems, and
2. Questions about configuring software.

Right now I feel that when referring to the second context this tag does not provide much taxonomic value. There is no fundamental difference when answering a question about configuring software rather than fixing an error.

That leaves a tag for operating system configuration. This does not really apply to a lot of questions currently tagged [setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setup). From the a randomly selected example of three questions...

1. [Are there any non-Linux operating systems available?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/33/46)
2. [How do I install an OS image onto an SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/931/46)
3. [How do I install new software?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/387/46)

None of them apply to configuring an operating system. In fact, the only ones I could find that were relevant are the following two.

1. [How would I write a one-off boot script?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1118/46)
2. [Which locale should I select during the Raspbian setup?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1132/46)

So what am I proposing? That we rename the [setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setup) tag to [os-config](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-config) and that the tag would apply to questions that meet the following description.

> Any question about the configuration of an operating system.

So for example, a question similar to the following would be on-topic.

> How do I set the device's hostname?

### Community?

Comment: Your suggestion would require us to retag all new questions because new users will never find `os-config`. I just don't think that's an intuitive enough name.

Comment: @Jivings We can always create a synonym from [tag:setup] to [tag:os-config].